# Set value of random memory address

Tags: c++, pointers

I understand that it probably isn't good practice to do the following. However, I was curious as to if it was possible?

```
x = 1;
cout << *(&x + 1) << endl; // Prints value at next memory address.
(&x + 1) = 0; // DOESN'T WORK.

// I want to set the value of the next memory address.
```

The error I get says:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Is there anything I can change to make this work, even though I understand that this probably isn't useful.

Comment: accessing memory you do not control is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver We have no idea if he does control that memory, because he didn't said what `x` is. `x` could be defined as such: `int a[2]; int& x = a;`

Comment: @Fireho in the code it could be but the question is `Set Value Of Random Memory Address` and it is unlikely they will have control of that random address.

Comment: @NathanOliver In this case, I think they're intentionally invoking that undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @Peter James Flanagan: Why did you use a `*` in the first case and then suddenly omitted it in the second? What was your logic behind omitting it?

Comment: Same reason you can't do `x + 1  = 5;`.

Comment: You can't be guaranteed that every address is accessible or that the address is defined.  For example, in some embedded systems there are address available but nothing exists there.  In bigger operating systems, the OS may not want you poking around in the address space, so it will prevent you from doing so.  In other systems, the addresses may be *virtual*, so you have no idea what you are accessing.

Comment: @PeterJamesFlanagan I think you pinged me by mistake.  I think you ment to ping Thomas Matthews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to you trying to assign to a temporary address.

```
(&x + 1) = 0;
```

What you probably meant was:

```
*(&x + 1) = 0;
```

The results of this expression depends on the type of `x`. If `x` is of type `int`, then this will result in undefined behaviour as you are effectively assigning to memory that have not been allocated.

However, using a type as the following will result in well defined behaviour for your example.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo& operator=(int i) { x[0] = i; return *this; }
    int* operator&() { return x.data(); }
    std::array<int, 2> x{{0}};
};

int main() {
    Foo x;
    x = 1;
    std::cout << *(&x + 1) << std::endl; // Equivalent to 'x.x[1]' which is '0'.
    *(&x + 1) = 0; // Ok.
}
```

In C++, it is always undefined behaviour to access memory that have not been previously allocated. The results of such an operation can result in pretty much anything as, e.g., the execution of a random instruction laying around in deallocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use the `*` operator.